# How to select some data labels to be shown in Scatter Plot Chart (Google Data Studio)

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-drive, google-spreadsheets

I've a massive amount of rows, therefore I have lots and lots of data labels:

[Huge amount of labels in Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hCQX.png)

How select some points to show labels and hide others?
(Or if it's not possible, is it possible for me to do it on Excel?)

Example:

| Jobs | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Electrical Engineer | 1 |
| Programming | 0.9 |

I wanted to show all values on the plot but only put a label on the Programming?

Comment: Are you looking for Slicer feature?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d

Answer (score 0):

Note: This solution is for Excel

Add a column with the following formula:

```
=IF(A2="Programming",A2,"")
```

On the chart, right-click on the labels and choose Format Data Labels from the popup menu

[image]

Under Label Options, select Values From Cells and choose the row you created above

[image]

Sample:

[image]